# Android Sync data in fixed interval of time

Tags: android

How we can sync the data in background of the android application within fixed interval of time.

Comment: Please explain your question with greater detail. What type of data, you are referring to?

Comment: Actuall we have some web services and we want to call them for sync the data in background to sync the data from server to the local database sqlite. If user add or update any data in server all the changes should be update after the time interval that's why we can store the data in sqlite db in android as an offline records.

Comment: Can you use Timer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877417/how-to-set-a-timer-in-android

Comment: If the application not running then it would be work in backgroud ?

Comment: You can use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774092/running-a-repeating-task-in-background-on-a-real-time-application

Comment: If you want to sync your data with the server, there is a better way of doing it, use C2DM PUSH messaging.